# Nice answer and Enlightened achievements refers to the question in the iOS app

Tags: bug, badges, ios-app, nice-answer

Recently I've got "Nice answer" badge and noticed that tapping on related achievement item in the iOS app refers me to the question instead of the answer:

> [image: ios]

Using web achievements panel refers to the answer as expected.

Same behavior for "Enlightened" badge.

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)

Comment: @Glorfindel Unbelievable! You have found a dupe of my own question :)